# Given alphabetic key and cipher text decrypt the cipher text

Tags: stream-cipher, pen-and-paper, affine-cipher

I've been at this for a while. I've been given two things

```
Ciphertext = bsaspp kkuosp
Key =        rsidpy dkawoa
```

Now seeing the domain that the characters are in. I naturally assumed an affine cipher and proceeded to decrypt it yet I yield gibberish as the plain text.

My steps are as following. Translate the letters to corresponding Integers. Then use them to complete the decryption.

CI:

```
b  (1) s (18) a  (0) s (18) p (15) p (15) k (10) k (10) u (20) o (14) s (18) p (15)
```

Key:

```
r (17) s (18) i  (8) d  (1) p (15) y (24) d  (3) k (10) a  (0) w (22) o (14) a  (0)
```

I yield these Numbers as the plain text

```
    9      0     17      7      0     16      7      0     20     17      4       15
```

Now would it be possible that the key was generated by another means or do I need more then just the key and cipher text to decrypt the message? I am thinking a stream cipher was used to make the key. If so will the same process work above?

Answer (score 1):

In general the key and ciphertext suffices, unless there are things missing such as an IV vector or other parameters. The trick is that you would still need to find the actual algorithm.

Although Kerckhoffs principle does apply, that doesn't mean that you are always able to find the algorithm given such small amounts of input. If the algorithm is secret or contains a secret itself they the principle states that your cipher becomes insecure if it just relies on that algorithm or secret key. Once *that* secret is out then all ciphertext would be broken. But that has not happened (yet).

As you're not given the algorithm all you can do is puzzle to try and find the algorithm, or just trying all algorithms that you can find. But that's OK, this looks like a puzzle to me, and most puzzles are written in such a way that it is possible to find an answer (and they are in general in line with what you've learned before).

Comment: Try modular addition, subtraction, multiplication etc.